# Connecting to uefi PXE server with virtualbox, using a VPN connection

Tags: networking, virtualbox, vpn, virtualization, pxe

I am on a Windows PC running VirtualBox with nothing installed in.

My PXE server is in UEFI mode. I changed the option in VirtualBox to UEFI boot and the only supported card type is the "paravirtualized network".

Now I need to connect my HOST computer to a VPN server (that is in another subnet where the PXE server is - but has access to it), bridge the connection to my guest PC and somewhat make the PXE client reach the PXE server.

I tried using NAT and Bridged connection for this, but without success.

I think the problem is in the DHCP server that serves the VPN subnet. Is there any way to solve this ? (eg. some modified PXE client that supports direct input of PXE IP address)

I cannot change settings in PXE server nor the VPN server.

Comment: Does your router have VPN tunnel functionality?

Comment: @harrymc I cannot access the router.

Comment: I might misunderstand: Why do you need VPN to connect the VM with the host?

Comment: @harrymc I need to connect my host to a VPN and then bridge the connection to my guest, so he can use the connection in the PXE environment.

Comment: But host and guest already have a direct connection, why add in a VPN?